# Get ID of parent element on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display ID of parent `UL` on `LI` click. but the alert is displaying value as undefined. Where am I going wrong?

HTML:

```
<ul id='uiID'>
    <li id='myLi'>A</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
var x = document.getElementById("myLI").parentNode.nodeName;
alert(x.id);
```

Comment: Case mismatch - `myLi` and `myLI`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're not attaching any click event to the element and `nodeName` in your case returns `LI`, so that's not wanted. What you want is

```
document.getElementById("myLI").onclick = function(e){
  alert(e.target.parentNode.id);
}
```

Comment: Probably cleaner to use `addEventListener` but `e.target.parentNode` is the correct way to find the parent of the actually clicked node

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this :

```
<ul id='uiID'>
   <li id='myLi' onclick="alert(this.parentNode.id)">A</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is case sensitive for most everything:

```
<li id='myLi'>A</li>
          ^^--- big L, small i

var x = document.getElementById("myLI").parentNode.nodeName;
                                   ^^---big L, big I
```

Since you're using an undefined ID, getElementById will return null for "no match found". Null has no "parentNode", hence your error.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");

console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul id='uiID'>
<li id='myLi'>A</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript(*you have to just remove ".nodeName" from x)

```
var x = document.getElementById("myLi").parentNode;
alert(x.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closest function to get parent too.
Get closest ul to my element.

var el = document.getElementById('myLi');

var r1 = el.closest("ul");

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.getElementById("myLI").parentElement.id

```html
<p>Example list:</p>

<ul id="ul-id">
  <li id="myLI">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to get the node name of the parent element of the li element in the list.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLI").parentElement.id;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```